# What are the main challenges for developing imaging techniques for cellular-scale structures?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, cell-biology, imaging, mri

Small disclaimer: I'm not a biologist, so I'll try my best to write a high-quality, objective question, but please forgive me if it doesn't turn out as expected.

Imaging technologies such as MRI and CT Scans are used routinely to inspect anatomical structures inside the body of alive patients, and, as such, are powerful diagnostic tools. A typical MRI machine will produce volumetric images with a voxel width of 1,000,000 nm. This is more than sufficient to identify a broad class of issues, such as tumors and aneurysms. Yet, given that a human cell has about 10 nm in diameter, that resolution is 5 orders of magnitude below what would be required to image individual cells in vivo. As such, MRI, and the like, can't be used to diagnose macular degeneration or hearing loss by imaging the damaged retinal or inner ear tissues, for example, and thus rely on less precise exams, such as hearing tests. At the same time, in vitro, technologies such as electron microscopy are capable of imaging individual structures inside cells, and are, thus, capable of reaching resolutions that are impossible for live patients. If we had some hypothetical imaging technique capable of inspecting individual cells, it would enable a wide range of conclusive diagnosis for conditions that, currently, are still hard to track.

My question is: why is there such a gap, and how far we are from developing technologies capable of imaging cellular-scale structures inside the body? For example, would it be possible to create a nano-MRI machine capable of imaging someone's organ of corti, or individual retinal ganglion cells? If so, what are the relevant advancements in this direction? If not, what are the physical or practical limits that make it impossible?

Comment: I think the question would be better focused on just MRI, and possibly a better fit over at Physics. It doesn't make much sense to compare MRI, which images through tissue using magnetic fields, to something like electron microscopy that requires you to slice into something and apply super carcinogenic chemicals to increase contrast. They're not in the same realm of approaches.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/621545/why-does-mri-magnetic-resonance-imaging-have-high-contrast-and-spatial-resolut https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111770/how-specifically-does-an-mri-machine-build-an-image-from-received-radio-waves